# Reset balance in truffle test accounts after each test

Tags: solidity, truffle, testing, unittesting

I am writing unit tests for a function where I am sending tokens from one address to other in exchange of ether. I ran these tests a few times and now I am left with 0 ether in one account. I tried searching online but couldn't find a way to reset the balances.

Is there a way to reset the balance back to 100 before and after running those tests. 
I am using truffle js to write the tests! http://truffleframework.com/docs/getting_started/javascript-tests

Comment: Are you talking about tests written in Solidity or JavaScript?

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue.  Never figured out how to reset the balances, but if you use the [ganache-cli provider](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-cli) you can configure how much ether your test accounts are given at the start, so you can bump that up from 100.  Alternatively you can use that capability to fund an extra account and then transfer eth from the "bank" account in a beforeEach.